# How to exclude a specific categories from tax calculation?

Tags: magento2, category, tax

In my country there's a specific items that doesn't have Tax on it. How to exclude these products categories from calculating tax on them in Magento 2.3.2

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude by creating catalog price rule  or cart price rule